# How to push PhoneGap into html tags?

Tags: javascript, android, sql, html, cordova

How do I query sql using javascript (jquery), limiting to one random result and then distribute the results into specific html tags?

Here's my`tag`:

> ```
> <div id= "title">
>     <div id="option_a"></div>
>     <div id="option_b"></div>
>     <div id="option_c"></div> 
> </div>
> ```

My sql has the same fields as the ids above.

Please help.
many thanks.

Comment: Hi I think you are mixing things up a little bit. jQuery is a Javascript library and not used to execute queries on SQL databases. If you want to query a sql database via jQuery you need a server who handles the requests. And finally: What has all this to do with Android?

Comment: Sorry, my apologies.  I meant PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the database tutorial at the [phonegap website](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). If you don't know how to insert DOM nodes into HTML read the [manipulation section](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) in the jQuery documentation.